# 2d array reverse

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a 2d array and compiler works  fine,but the array is still remaing the same as the beggining..

I print the array before calling reverse function and after but no changes seems to have take place..
Why ?

Here is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void reverse(int table[ ][5]){
    int a,b,c,d;
    int temp = 0;
    for(a=0,c=3;a<=3;a++,c--){
        for(b=0,d=4;b<=4;b++,d--){
            temp = table[a][b];
            table[a][b]= table[c][d];
            table[c][d]= temp;      
        }
      }

    }

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int i,j;
    int table[4][5];

    for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
       for(j=0;j<=4;j++){
          scanf("%d",&table[i][j]);
       }
    }

    for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=4;j++){
            printf(" %d",table[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    reverse (table);


    for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
       for(j=0;j<=4;j++){
           printf("%d ",table[i][j]);
       }
    }

    return 0; 
    }
```

Can you find the problem in reverse function ??

Comment: How many times do you swap `table[3][4]`? Count them.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're swapping the elements, then swapping them back.

Comment: +1 @rain If this causes a segfault, you should mention it in your question. As for the reason for why your code doesn't work this answer states it correctly: you're swapping each pair of elements twice. It's easy to see if you just count all the swaps.

Comment: @AdamZalcman, what caused segmentation fault (I think) was the incorrect and edited out suggestion to change `reverse(int table[][5])` to `reverse(int **table)`.

Comment: @eq: Actually this caused seg fault !

Comment: @rain..., how can this cause a segfault in it's current form?

Comment: @eq :I guess because table itself is int* ant if you put another * it is made int***..But if you write it like table[][5] it means int **

Comment: @rain..., no, `table[][5]` does not mean `**table`. However, nothing in this answer in it's current form suggests putting another `*`. As I said earlier, the (edited out suggestion to) change from `table[][5]` to `**table` would certainly be able to cause a segfault.

Comment: @eq...Anyway,when i put int**table compiler shows "note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int ( * )[5]’ " That's why I am saying that table means int *

Answer (score 1):

In your reverse function, you are swapping the matrix. When the loops reach half way, the 2-d array is swapped completely. But you iterate from half way to full, it gets swapped again, making it to same as original.

You need to update your loop something like

```
for(a=0,c=3;a<=(3/2)+1;a++,c--){
    for(b=0,d=4;b<=4/2;b++,d--){
-------------------^
```

Note: you need to take care for odd length appropriately, as `3/2` will give you `1` but you will need `2`.